# Design considerations for high-reliability service

Tags: c#, service, reliability

I am writing a c# windows service which will perform some background processing - basically it is a consumer for a work queue.

It needs to not go down (stop processing new items), and if it does go down I need to be notified.

What are some design guidelines and considerations for a) ensuring that such a service is as reliable as possible, and b) sending out a notification if something does go wrong? I have considered, for instance, creating a watcher thread whose only job is to make sure the worker thread is still processing jobs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that you can do here to help improve the reliability, as well as gauge that you have a solution that is going to meet your needs.

**Testing**

First and foremost though, the testing process that you go through will need to be a very solid one, test for those "unexpected" situations, loss of network connection, etc.  Make sure that you are testing those, and seeing what is happening.  Notification on failure, can be a bit of a "mixed bag".  For example, you can't e-mail yourself if you don't have network connections available.

**Proper Code Design**

In addition to setting up valid test scenarios, be sure that your code is a bullet proof as possible, since you are creating a windows service, be sure that you are capturing, logging, and dealing with all errors possible, as if an error bubbles up to the OS, your service will go down.

**Monitoring**

Consider putting monitoring, in my day-job we have two types of monitoring used, errors are reported the the Windows Event log in some cases and Microsoft MOM is used to notify us of any/all issues that are going on in the environment.  A second process that we use is a second scheduled job that every X minutes validates that the critical job is in a "Started" state, if it isn't in a started state, it will re-start it.  Not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think a MOM and/or Solar Winds or some other monitoring application which your system administrator might be using to monitor the machine on which the service is deployed & take proper action (send email, ring phones :)